Issue with Slider Filtering on Landing Page
I'm building a landing page using Gulp and trying to implement a slider with filtering. I found an example on CodePen (https://codepen.io/chiz-developer/pen/ybxBKy) that demonstrates how to do this. However, when I apply a similar approach to my landing page, I encounter a problem: when I click the filter buttons, my slider disappears. Everything reappears when I click the "All" button.
<section class="section product">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="product__filter product__filter-buttons">
        <button class="product__filter-btn product__all"   data-filter="all" type="button">All</button>
        <button class="product__filter-btn product__chair" data-filter="product__chair" type="button">Chair</button>
        <button class="product__filter-btn product__beds"  data-filter="product__beds" type="button">Beds</button>
        <button class="product__filter-btn product__sofa"  data-filter="product__sofa" type="button">Sofa</button>
        <button class="product__filter-btn product__lamp"  data-filter="product__lamp" type="button">Lamp</button>        
      </div>

      <ul class="product__slider">
        <li class="product__slide product__sofa">
          <article class="productCart">
            <img class="productCart__img" src="images/product/nyantuy.png" alt="">
            <div class="productCart__content">
              <p class="productCart__subtitle">Chair</p>
              <h3 class="productCart__title">Anjay Chair</h3>
              </div>
          </article>
        </li>

        <li class="product__slide product__chair">
          <article class="productCart">
            <img class="productCart__img" src="images/product/anjay.png" alt="">
            <div class="productCart__content">
              <p class="productCart__subtitle">Chair</p>
              <h3 class="productCart__title">Anjay Chair</h3>
              </div>
          </article>
        </li>

        <li class="product__slide product__beds">
          <article class="productCart">
            <img class="productCart__img" src="images/product/baltsar.png" alt="">
            <div class="productCart__content">
              <p class="productCart__subtitle">Chair</p>
              <h3 class="productCart__title">Anjay Chair</h3>
              </div>
          </article>
        </li>

        <li class="product__slide product__lamp">
          <article class="productCart">
            <img class="productCart__img" src="images/product/sakarias.png" alt="">
            <div class="productCart__content">
              <p class="productCart__subtitle">Chair</p>
              <h3 class="productCart__title">Anjay Chair</h3>
              </div>
          </article>
        </li>
      </ul>

    </div>
  </section>

$(function() {
  $(".product__slider").slick({
    slidesToShow: 4,
    slidesToScroll: 4,
    arrows: true,
  });
  
  $(".product__filter-btn").on('click', function() {
    var filter = $(this).data('filter');

    // Перевірте наявність слайдерів перед фільтрацією
    if ($(".product__slider").slick('getSlick').$slides.length === 0) {
      console.log('Слайдери не знайдені');
      return;
    }

    $(".product__slider").slick('slickUnfilter');

    if (filter === 'product__chair') {
      $(".product__slider").slick('slickFilter', '.product__chair');
    } else if (filter === 'product__beds') {
      $(".product__slider").slick('slickFilter', '.product__beds');
    } else if (filter === 'product__sofa') {
      $(".product__slider").slick('slickFilter', '.product__sofa');
    } else if (filter === 'product__lamp') {
      $(".product__slider").slick('slickFilter', '.product__lamp');
    } else if (filter === 'all') {
      $(".product__slider").slick('slickUnfilter');
    }
    
    // Перевірка фільтрації
    console.log('Активний фільтр:', filter);
  });
});

I’m a beginner in JavaScript and web development, so I might have made a mistake. Could you help me figure out what might be going wrong and suggest alternative solutions for implementing slider filtering?
I would greatly appreciate any assistance!
Thank you!
